# How do I set ACL's in Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6, acl

I need set an ACL in Parse, but I do not know where to put the code.

The code in Objective-C is as follows:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

user.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:user];
```

Where do I put this? Also; do anyone know how to translate this to swift?

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this earlier for a UserPhoto class on Parse in Swift. This is code within a func that is called when the user chooses a new image. The ACL part is on line 4:

```
var userPhoto = PFObject(className: "UserPhoto")
//imageFile is NSData passed to func
userPhoto.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "imageFile")
userPhoto.ACL = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser())
userPhoto.setObject(PFUser.currentUser(), forKey: "user")
//save
userPhoto.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
    println("Saved new userPhoto to Parse")
})
```

Hope it helps!